# How can i use infinite PageView?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

In the last week I couldn’t’ fix a problem with my app. The problem is I can’t figure out how to use pageview pages separately. Basically i want to add/subtract numbers in one page but don't want to change the numbers on the other ones.

This is my code:

https://gist.github.com/Matelevi12/1d847efe5ace8a25d4676a32332ebd85

Please help me it’s really annoying. I read every article online, but nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an array of numbers then for each page.

if you have 3 pages then store the numbers in an array like this

```
var arrayOfNumbers = [5,5,5];
```

Then access them using the page index. Use the `PageController` to access the currently selected page and call that index from the array to retrieve the value saved in the array for that page. If current page is 1 then use `arrayOfNumbers[1]` to get the specific value for that page.

Comment: Okey, This is helpful so far, but I will use 30k pages, also how should i store the numbers to the arreyOfnumbers or where should i write the code for the index call?

Comment: You can modify your existing methods like this:
`void subtractNumbers(int selectedIndex) {
    setState(() {
      arrayOfNumbers[selectedIndex] = arrayOfNumbers[selectedIndex] - 1;
    });
  }
  void addNumbers(int selectedIndex) {
    setState(() {
       arrayOfNumbers[selectedIndex] = arrayOfNumbers[selectedIndex] +1;
    });
  }`

Comment: Thats pretty good and helpful. Thank you. Can you help me with one more thig. How to use the onPressed function now?

Comment: You can use it like
`onPressed : (){
   subtractNumbers(2)
}`